# Forzar un input para que solo acepte números

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo **un `input` en un formulario con ReactJS que sólo debe aceptar números (13 dígitos).**

Soy nuevo con *ReactJS* y lo intente de 2 maneras pero no me funciono...

```
<input
     type="number"
     name="dpi_paciente"
     className="u-full-width"
     placeholder="DPI"
     onChange={actualizarState}
     value={dpi_paciente}
     maxLength="16"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Acá te comparto un ejemplo que cumple con lo siguiente:**

- El input solo acepta números.
- El input solo acepta un máximo de 13 dígitos

**Como tal hay dos puntos esenciales para que se cumplan estas validaciones**

1. Agregue el [pattern](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145) como atributo del input lo cual me permite validar el valor en base a una expresión regular donde le indico que solo pueden ser números y un máximo de 13 dígitos.

```
pattern="[0-9]{0,13}"
```

2. Cuando el input intenta cambiar su valor entonces se pregunta si el nuevo valor es válido.

```
const esValido = e.target.validity.valid;
```

**Ejemplo online:** https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-water-2fe74

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    dpi_paciente: ""
  };

  actualizarState = e => {
    const esValido = e.target.validity.valid;

    if (esValido) {
      this.setState({
        dpi_paciente: e.target.value
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      actualizarState,
      state: { dpi_paciente }
    } = this;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="dpi_paciente"
          className="u-full-width"
          placeholder="DPI"
          value={dpi_paciente}
          pattern="[0-9]{0,13}"
          onChange={actualizarState}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: lo mejor es utilizar las expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 1):

Ya probo poner type="number"?. o puede en el metodo actualizarState validar que el ultimo elemento ingresado sea númerico

```
if(dpi_paciente.substr(dpi_paciente.size()-1, 1) >= 0 || dpi_paciente.substr(dpi_paciente.size()-1, 1) <= 9){ aqui actualiza el estado }
```

espero le ayude

Answer (score 1):

> Si agregas como atributo la siguiente funcion `onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==13) return false;"` vas a poder simular lo que necesitas.

```html
<input
     type="number"
     name="dpi_paciente"
     className="u-full-width"
     placeholder="DPI"
     onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==13) return false;" 
/>
```

Comment: a este le entra la e.

Comment: @RicardoSaucedaRojas la letra 'e' en matematicas, hace refencia a un numero exponencial. No la reconoce como texto, sino que la usa para operar. Es para trabajar con numeros extremadamente grandes o extremadamente pequeños

Comment: wow, gracias! aprecio tu comentario.

Answer (score 1):

puedes utilizar esto dentro del componente:

````javascript
onKeyDown={function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode < '48' || e.keyCode > '57') {
        e.preventDefault()
     }
 }}```
````

Comment: **¿Qué hace este código?** Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, lee [answer] y también [por qué es importante explicar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/).

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar una funcion que compruebe el tamano del valor actual del input, si es menor que 16 entonces actualizas el valor

```js
update(event, value) {
  if (value.length <= 16) {
    setValue(value)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value={value} onChange={(e,v)=> update(e,v)}/>
```